# View to Bitmap to PDF rendering only on second attempt & massive file- How to resize with my configuration?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bitmap

I want my PDF to render properly and instantly as they normally render, on first try & with reasonable file size and resolution.

Actual results:

Clicking "print button" the first time produces a blank page in print adapter. This also takes around 5 seconds to render. Clicking "print button" a second time takes 5 seconds or more to finally load the PDF. Additionally, the PDF file is a staggering 2.16MB for a 1 page output.

I believe this must be a memory problem, understandably.

What I'm doing:

I have a relatively large view fully rendered, its invisible to user and in a print friendly color sceme to be printed. It measures 900dp X 300dp. This is a sort of tableview/scrollview dependency, pretty much a super simple spreadsheet with some numbers. I load this view into a View to Bitmap capturing dependency. I then load this into the android provided print helper for printing a Bitmap.

Dependency:

https://github.com/HelloHuDi/ViewCapture

My button click code:

```
        printableVersion.setOnClickListener {

        printChartCreate(unitDimensionImperialEven.text.toString().toInt()) // Create chart
        val bitmap: Bitmap? = ViewCapture.with(printableTableMetricCoursing).bitmap // I guess this initializes bitmap from chart
        bitmap.set
        this.also { context ->
            PrintHelper(context).apply {
                scaleMode = PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FILL
            }.also { printHelper ->
                printHelper.printBitmap("droids.jpg - test print", bitmap!!)
            }
        }
    }
```

So far I've tried implementing `bitmap.createBitmap()` method so to recreate the bitmap with a lower resolution but get errors and crash with everything i've tried. The current resolution/inch on inspection is 520dpi. How can I reduce the resolution with this configuration above to 300 or less? I believe this smaller file will solve all the above problems.

EDIT: I've also tried 3 different bitmap capturing dependencies and this is the same output or crashes.

Comment: "How can I reduce the resolution with this configuration above to 300 or less?" -- you're the one who chose the 900dp x 300dp resolution. If you do not want that resolution, choose another resolution. A better solution IMHO is to render your table in HTML and use a `WebView` and [print that](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs). And better than either of those is to use some library (e.g., iText) that is designed for creating PDF *files*, as the PDF classes that you are using are designed for printing.

Comment: Hmmm, i guess there is more to the story now that I think of it. I had no choice to render the size 900x300 because that is the size of the entire chart. I tried for literally weeks to find a way or dependency to capture my entire chart as scrollview but it didn't work. I tried iText and others. I tried probably 150 different combinations of code and probably 15 different dependancies, see here- no help, but im close now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64655973/how-to-screenshot-or-save-view-of-multiplescrolltableview-dependency ... thats why i want to step down resolution after render...

Comment: When I suggested iText, it wasn't with an eye towards you still doing this view-capture thing. It was for generating a PDF file containing your desired content, using standard PDF text rendering and the like, the way PDF reports have been created for the past 20 years or so.

Comment: Thats definitely an option i will look into.